# Как сделать references с одного поля на несколько таблиц в PostgresSQL одновременно?

Tags: postgresql

Есть 3 таблицы `tasks` `comments` и `files_tasks`. У таблицы `tasks` есть поле `code_task` на которое должно ссылаться поле `code_task` таблицы `comments`, это уже есть, но на него должно одновременно еще и ссылаться `code_task` в таблице `files_tasks`.

Подскажите как сделать такую двойную ссылку?

```
--create table with tasks.
create table if not exists tasks(
    code_task serial PRIMARY KEY not null references comments(code_task), -- и плюс files_tasks(code_task) но как?
    user_id integer,
    name_task char(50),
    description text,
    state char(10),
    category char(20),
    create_time timestamp,
);

--create table with comments.
create table if not exists comments(
    code_comment serial PRIMARY KEY,
    code_task integer,
    body_comment text,
    create_time timestamp,
    user_id integer,
    role_id integer not null
);

--create table with files of tasks paths.
create table if not exists files_tasks(
    file_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    file_path text NOT NULL,
    code_task integer,
);
```

Comment: `У таблицы tasks есть поле code_task которое должно ссылаться поле code_task таблицы comments` Наоборот. `оно должно одновременно еще и ссылаться на code_task в таблице files_tasks` Тоже наоборот.

Comment: А `code_task serial PRIMARY KEY not null references comments(code_task)` так и вовсе достойно башорга...

Comment: @Akina, иногда PK может быть одновременно и FK на другую таблицу. Но явно не в данном случае

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Угу... может. Но тут-то FK на другую таблицу, и при этом - автоинкремент!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`REFERENCES` это один из способов описать внешний ключ. Но не единственный. Вот две равносильных записи, демонстрирующих ещё один способ:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  a integer PRIMARY KEY,
  b integer REFERENCES other_table (c1)
);

CREATE TABLE t1 (
  a integer PRIMARY KEY,
  b integer,
  FOREIGN KEY (b) REFERENCES other_table (c1) -- <- особенно на эту строчку
);
```

Вторым способом, в отличие от первого, можно (а) привязать одну колонку к нескольким другим, (б) делать *составные* внешние ключи (из нескольких колонок). Для вашего случая будет запись следующего вида:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  a integer PRIMARY KEY,
  b integer,
  FOREIGN KEY (b) REFERENCES other_table (c1),
  FOREIGN KEY (b) REFERENCES and_another_table (c2)
);
```

---

Подробнее в [документации о внешних ключах](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK).

Comment: `Для вашего случая будет запись следующего вида` Вы зря не посмотрели описание связей. Для описанного в вопросе случая так НЕ будет.

Comment: @Akina это самый что ни на есть прямой ответ на вопрос, указанный в коде. Если мы реально тут имеем XY-проблему (что ТС нужно не то, что он просит), это совсем другой разговор. Ответ мне не жалко, если ТС нужно другое, пусть поправит вопрос, я грохну ответ (может, потом исправлю).

Comment: `ТС нужно не то, что он просит` Согласен.